# Referrer spoofed but google analytic do not show that

Tags: google-analytics, http-headers, fiddler, spoofing

I spoofed referrer with Fiddler Web Debugger 4.5 using this code:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    oSession.oRequest["Referer"] = "http://ehsan.com";
```

And when I request, I can see in the miscellaneous part that referrer is my website. but the google analytic says No referrer. what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is likely using JavaScript (document.referrer) instead of HTTP to determine what the referrer is. You can try to inject a snippet of JavaScript that sets document.referrer to fool it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what can I do if I do not have access to the visited page? I want to visit a third party web page and tell it the refer is my web?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your goal is here. If you're just testing this by yourself, you can use Fiddler to inject something like ```<script>document.referrer='http://example.com'</script>```. If you want to change the referrer Google records for other visitors on a page you can't control, it's not possible.